# Find all values of $n$ for which the Diophantine equation $n=a^2-b^2$ has a solution

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $n$ be an integer. Find all values of $n$ for which the Diophantine equation $n=a^2-b^2$ has a solution for integers $a$ and $b$. For those values of $n$ found in the previous part find all solutions of $n=a^2-b^2$ for integers $a$ and $b$.

The first part is pretty easy. It is just if $n$ is the product of at least $2$ factors of $2$ or $n$ is the product of solely odd factors.

For the second part, I used this argument. If $n$ is the product of at least two factors of $2$, then let $a+b$ be any factor of $n$ with at least one power of $2$ but less than or equal to one minus the maximum power of $2$ dividing $n$. The value of $a-b$ is just the other part of $n$. On the other hand, if $n$ is the product of solely odd numbers, let $a+b$ be an odd factor of $n$. Then the value of $a-b$ follows and this yields all integer solutions $a, b$.

Is it necessary to formalize my argument into algebra and number theory or is how I put it fine?

Comment: This is not the simplest way to express the answer: "It is just if $n$ is the product of at least $2$ factors of $2$ or $n$ is the product of solely odd factors." You could just say that $n$ is a multiple of $4$ or it is odd.

Comment: Other than that is the method okay?

Comment: It's too verbose. If $n=4k$ then any factorization $k=uv$ yields a solution. If $n$ is odd, any factorization $n=uv$ yields a solution. "with at least one power of $2$ but less than or equal to one minus the maximum power of $2$ dividing $n$" is quite a mouthful. Simplify.

Comment: But it is true though it can't contain all the factors of $2$. If it did then we wouldn't have an integral solution.

Comment: Once you have a factorization $k=uv$, you have a factorization $n=4k=(2u)(2v)$ which satisfies your condition without all the words. You can either express this as  looking for factorization of $4k$ with conditions that are quite complicated,  or you can express this as seeking a factorization of $k$ with no conditions.

Comment: What if $n = 8$? Then is $k = 2*1$ a valid factorization here?

Comment: Then your factorization of $8$ is $(2\cdot 2)\cdot (2\cdot 1)$, which is a valid factorization of $8$, so yes. And then your solution is $a=2+1,b=2-1$. In general, if $k=uv$, then $4k = (u+v)^2-(u-v)^2$.

Comment: For the odd case: if $n=(2u+1)(2v+1)$ then $n=(u+v+1)^2-(u-v)^2$.

Comment: to me "$n$ is the product of at least two factors of $2$" sends the wrong message, I take this to mean that $n$ has two or more factors of $2$ AND no other factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $$n=a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$ is solveable over the integers if and only if there are numbers $u,v$ with $uv=n$, such that the system $$a-b=u$$ $$a+b=v$$
is solveable over the integers.

The system is solveable if and only if $u$ and $v$ have the same parity. We can find suitable $u$ and $v$, if and only if $n\ne 2\ (\ mod\ 4\ )$. If $n$ is odd, we can simply choose $u=1$ , $v=n$. If $n$ is divisble by $4$, we can choose two even numbers $u,v$ with $uv=n$. In the case $n\equiv 2\ (\ mod\ 4\ )$, one of the factors will be odd and the other even.

So, $n=a^2-b^2$ is solveable over the integers, if and only if $n\ne 2\ (\ mod\ 4\ )$.